# How to dynamically import Vue 3 component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, components, vuejs3

According [this article](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/) I would like to import component to view dynamically to my Vue 3 app. The code of the view looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="page">
      <latest-box v-if="showLatestBox" />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
// This works well. 
//import LatestBox from '@/components/LatestBox.vue'


export default {
    name: 'Page 1',

    data() {
        return {
            showLatestBox: true,
        }
    },

    components: {
        LatestBox: () => import('@/components/LatestBox.vue')  // This does not work
    }
}
</script>
```

Code does not throw any errors but I dont see the component on the page. If I use first import style it works. Am I missing somethig?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use `defineAsyncComponent` in Vue 3 to lazy load components

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
...
    components: {
        LatestBox: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@/components/LatestBox.vue'))
    }
```

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#overview

Comment: As the link now redirects to the vuejs front page, here is the link to the related guide: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html

Comment: I love you - I needed this for a project I'm working on that supports many different types of complex editors, so only ever wanted to load the one that was actually needed.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Works as a charm.