# Configure base URL in Vite

Tags: node.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a Vue 3 application that I am building with Vite. Given the config file below, how do I tell Vite where to load my files from?  On the server, the root path of the app is `/app/` but Vite is assuming it's in the root path so lazy-loaded Vue views are being loaded from `/` instead of `/app/GeneratedFileName.js`

My server for both dev and production is a .NET Core based application.  I am not using the Node-based dev server at all.

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue' 

const path = require('path');
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({

  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),      
    }
  }, 
  build: {
    outDir:'../wwwroot/app',
    manifest:true,
    
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [            
        '/img/icons/icons.svg',
        'bootstrap' 
      ],      
      input: { 
      cards: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/pages/cards/cards.ts', import.meta.url)), 
      output: { 
        entryFileNames: `[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `chunks/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }      
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    assetsDir: 'assets', 
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },  
})
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Is the problem at runtime, when you run the app, and the page doesn't serve properly the scripts, or is it at build time? I also work with .Net and I am having a hard time figuring out how all these pieces fit together with the .Net Core stuff - I am also using a layout page and so on. it might help to show some directory structure.

Comment: One of the problems at runtime is that the references to the js files in the dist index.html file begin with `/`, while when you use cshtml pages, you can reference them with `~/`. Imo, you should always use your own cshtml files and ignore the generated html files. But it means you have to make the names of the generated js/css files predictable (you did this according to the vite.config.js above) and add the cache buster in the cshtml. I used in the past an app version number.

Comment: Could this help: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base, and specify a relative path? Or this: https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#advanced-base-options

Comment: If you set `base: './'` under `build:{` the url generated is: `<link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="./assets/index-7587de24.js">` as an example.

Comment: I've updated the question and also answered it below.  It was related to async SFCs that are loaded at runtime needing to be wrapped in defineAsyncComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific issue was not related to Vite, but rather rater related to dynamic imports.  In Vue 2, you only needed to do this:

`public glyph = () => import('./GlyphCard.vue')`

In Vue 3, that won't work and you need to do this:

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
public glyph =() => defineAsyncComponent(()=> import('./GlyphCard.vue'))
```

Documentation: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#overview

Related question: [How to dynamically import Vue 3 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559313/how-to-dynamically-import-vue-3-component)